# Descriptografar sha512

Tags: javascript, node.js, criptografia

É possível descriptografar sha512?
Se sim tem algum site com o algorítimo ou um pacote do node que possam me indicar?

Comment: SHA é um algoritmo de hash, não de criptografia, então não tem como voltar ao valor original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sha não é uma forma de criptografia, não tem como voltar ao valor original.
Se precisar de criptografia, dê uma olhada [Crypto-js](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/#Ciphers)

> Um hash (ou escrutínio) é uma sequência de bits geradas por um algoritmo de dispersão, em geral representada em base hexadecimal, que permite a visualização em letras e números (0 a 9 e A a F), representando um nibble cada. O conceito teórico diz que "hash é a transformação de uma grande quantidade de dados em uma pequena quantidade de informações".
>
> Essa sequência busca identificar um arquivo ou informação unicamente. Por exemplo, uma mensagem de correio eletrônico, uma senha, uma chave criptográfica ou mesmo um arquivo. É um método para transformar dados de tal forma que o resultado seja (quase) exclusivo. Além disso, funções usadas em criptografia garantem que não é possível a partir de um valor de hash retornar à informação original.

*Fonte Wikipedia*

**Além disso, funções usadas em criptografia garantem que não é possível a partir de um valor de hash retornar à informação original.**